# How to create a square LinkedIn OG image when sharing a link?

Tags: share-open-graph

I found the post where they shared the link, and their image is square (555x555), even though in all the documents they state that it supports a 1.91:1 ratio. Do you know how to do this? I see that they don't link to any exact file, but refer to the API in the meta tag, but I can't find how they do it.

[The linked post link](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/easy-software-ltd._easy-redmine-reveals-its-new-feature-developed-activity-7123232442240368640-GNFc/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop)

[image]